# Access blocked by CORS policy

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, axios, cors

I recently started learning web development, appreciated if someone could help me fix CORS policy error.

I am trying to connect my React application with my node.js application. I am using axios http service.

http service setup in react application.

```
import axios from "axios";
import { toast } from "react-toastify";

axios.defaults.baseURL = process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL;
// axios.defaults.headers.common["Access-Control-Allow-Origin"] = "*";
axios.defaults.headers.post["Content-Type"] =
  "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

console.log(axios.defaults.baseURL);

axios.interceptors.response.use(null, (error) => {
  const expectedError =
    error.response &&
    error.response.status >= 400 &&
    error.response.status < 500;

  if (!expectedError) {
    console.log("Logging the error", error);
    console.log(error.response);
    // toast.error("Unexpected error occured");
  }

  return Promise.reject(error);
});


export default {
  get: axios.get,
  post: axios.post,
};
```

using http service to make get and post to back end.

```
import http from "./httpService";

const apiEndPoint = "/email";

export function sendMail(sender) {
  // console.log(sender);
  return http.post(apiEndPoint, {
    name: sender.name,
    email: sender.email,
    phone: sender.phone,
    company: sender.company,
    message: sender.message,
  });

  // return http.get(apiEndPoint);
}
```

Back end http get and post methods.

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const { validate } = require("../model/contact");
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");

router.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.header({ "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*" }).send("Hello world");
});

router.post("/", (req, res) => {
  res.header({ "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*" });

  const { error } = validate(req.body);
  console.log(error);
  if (error) return res.send(error.details[0].message);

  const output = `
    <p>You have a new contact request</p>
    <h3>Contact Details</h3>
    <ul>
      <li>Name: ${req.body.name}</li>
      <li>Company: ${req.body.company}</li>
      <li>Email: ${req.body.email}</li>
      <li>Phone: ${req.body.phone}</li>
    </ul>
    <h3>Message</h3>
    <p>${req.body.message}</p>
  `;

  // create reusable transporter object using the default SMTP transport
  let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: "smtp.gmail.com",
    port: 465,
    secure: true, // true for 465, false for other ports
    auth: {
      user: "XXXX", // generated ethereal user
      pass: "XXXX", // generated ethereal password
    },
    tls: {
      rejectUnauthorized: false,
    },
  });

  // setup email data with unicode symbols
  let mailOptions = {
    from: '"Nodemailer Contact" XXXX', // sender address
    to: "XXX", // list of receivers
    subject: "Node Contact Request", // Subject line
    text: "Hello world", // plain text body
    html: output, // html body
  };

  // send mail with defined transport object
  transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
    if (error) {
      return console.log(error);
    }
    console.log("Message sent: %s", info.messageId);
    console.log("Preview URL: %s", nodemailer.getTestMessageUrl(info));

    res.send("Email Sent!!");
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

I have also set the proxy on both client and server.

surprisingly get request is working but post request throws CORS error.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: consider using the express cors module. you need to handle `OPTIONS` requests

Comment: @DanielA.White Thanks for your reply, I did try cors module yet, no luck. Not sure if Im doing anything wrong.

Answer (score -1):

Like Daniel said in the comment, you should probably use the [the cors module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors) rather than setting headers directly in this case.

The bit about GET working but POST not is the big giveaway to what's going on. When you do a cross-domain POST, browsers do use a [preflight request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request) with the `OPTIONS` http verb to see what sort of stuff the endpoint supports (since POST requests can be quite large the idea is that it saves on bandwidth and a few other things). If you use the module, this will be taken care of for you. Alternately you can implement it yourself.

Comment: Thanks for your Answer. I did try cors module. No Luck so far.